# hdparm vs /dev/zero in hdd erase

Tags: hard-drive, disk-cleanup, hdparm

So, what is more secure and why?

```
hdparm --security-erase-enhanced NULL /dev/sdX
```

or

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They use different methods, and the effectiveness may depend on the drive. The former uses the 'newer' [ATA secure erase](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) command and the latter just overwrites it with zeros.

For really old drives that don't have ata secure erase supported, the latter is the only way to do it - it just overwrites the drive with zeros and in many cases thats enough (though using something like the shred command is better - since its designed specifically to wipe out data, unlike DD). Most drive wouldn't be accessible after a wipe.

However, with SSDs, data is intentionally internally scrambled and stored for wear levelling purposes. overwriting it with zeros *should* work, but it isn't certain - in which case doing a sata secure erase is a better solution. It may also provide a s[hort term performance boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_amplification#Secure_erase) on a drive that is suffering from write amplification. Sata secure erase will trigger the internal erasure method, and is the best way to be assured of a wipe.

In most modern drives the hdparm method should be sufficient and reliable enough to use. If you need to zero out a drive for whatever reason, use the dd method.

Comment: If overwriting from `/dev/zero` seems insufficient, one could additionally make a second run with `/dev/random` as source. Btw: SSDs use NAND-Flash, don't they? So if you instead use `/dev/random` as source, this should trigger the internal block erasure in most cases. Still, writes to NAND-Flash devices should be minimized as much as possible, if you want to increase the lifespan of those devices - they have a limited "write-count".

Comment: With SSDs ATA secure erase is a much better idea since you KNOW it triggers a internal block erase. Anything else is a crapshoot.

Comment: Ah, OK -- thank you for that detail. ATA secure erase I haven't heard of before, so please forgive me my ignorance concerning this piece ;) Maybe you want to add this detail to your answer directly -- e.g. behind "better solution, as it for sure triggers..." or the like?

Comment: Note that hdparm imposes a timeout based on how long the drive reports that its security erase should take.  (This is shown in the security section of the `hdparm -I` output.)  If the drive doesn't provide that information, hdparm assumes a hard-coded limit of 3 hours.  There are some (older) drives that don't report how long an erase takes, but take more than 3 hours, so hdparm will stop waiting and reset the drive before the erase is done.  Be careful about this if you don't see a line like "322min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT" in your `hdparm -I` output.